# inline image class are present in content on single post page, but removed from excerpt in homepage

Tags: wordpress, class

I have inline images in my post content that have classes. the classes are available as I go to single page like this:

```
<img src="the_cource.jpg" class="myclass">
```

, but are removed as I look at them on my homepage by using excerpt.

```
<img src="the_cource.jpg">
```

does wordpress manipulate the classes, in excerpt?

Comment: Same thing here.please help!

Comment: Of course they are dislpaying only on the single page, they are set up to work in single page only. Excerpt have nothing to do with single page. The theme creator built it that way, so if you want to add that same class to any image on the homepage just add the `class="myclass"` like the example you gave us to make your image styling to be like in your single page.

Comment: @Chun thanks for your response. I dont want to `add` any classes, I just want to preserve theme as the were in my content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a yes or no question, and the answer is 'no'. Normally, dynamic excepts are created from the content of a post, and has nothing to do with images. If images are being displayed and the classes are being modified from one template to another, it's something happening in your THEME, and not something that's happening because of the Wordpress core.

Answer (score 0):

Yes WordPress removes a lot of content in an excerpt. By definition, the excerpt is only text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the images are inline with text. the excerpt does not remove the <img> tag, but its class attribute.